# how to set default web page while opening new tab in web browser?

Tags: browser, settings

I am using Firefox as my default web browser. In that when I opening new tab (Ctrl+T), an empty page (blank page) is being opened. But now I want to load my default page when I open the new tab. Please guide me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Glad you found your solution, but keep in mind for the future this kind of question is more fit to superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that directly in firefox.

There is however this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/777/